# Formatting facet pie chart ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a sample data frame as follows:

```
set.seed(87)
df = data.frame(
  sample = rep(c("PB","PB","BM","BM"),8),
  status = rep(c("healthy","myeloma"),16),
  family = c(rep("CD4",16),rep("CD8",16)),
  phenotype = rep(c("Tn","Tn","Tn","Tn","Tcm","Tcm","Tcm","Tcm","Tem","Tem","Tem","Tem","Temra","Temra","Temra","Temra"),2),
  percent = sample(20:30,32,replace=T)
)
```

I want to plot the data in pie chart format also with faceting in both the x and y axis formatted like this nice diagram I found online:

[image]

However I only know how to facet by grouping the two variables (CD4/CD8 and healthy/myeloma) together first with the following code which can't give me the nice separation of the x axis variables into two rows:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(group = paste(family,status)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = "",y=percent,fill = phenotype)) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  facet_grid(sample~group) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]

Appreciate any ideas on how to make the whole diagram look more like the one online, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is closer -

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  mutate(group = paste(family,status)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = "",y=percent,fill = phenotype)) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  facet_grid(sample~group) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 15, face = 'bold'),
        legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]